# Como detectar warning Deferred long-running timer task(s)?

Tags: apache-cordova, webkit

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) esse erro começou aparecer depois de utilizar alguns métodos (depois que esse warning ocorre a função para de ser chamada).

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de eu detectar quando isso acontecer para refazer a chamada da minha função que foi bloqueada. Pelo que pesquisei ele bloqueia funções que "abusam" do setTimeout.

> Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness.
>   See http://crbug.com/574343.